# Load Logback config from the library in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, spring-logback

I'm trying to build a logging library which will be used across my services. I would like it to come with a default Logback configuration (predefined appenders). Is there a way to tell the application to load that config when the library is added to the project?

Ideally i would like to have this in the library, in application.yml

```
logging:
  config: classpath:logback.xml
```

Application should use that configuration, and also allow to load custom application Logback config if developer wants to override the one.